# Merge two dataframes r for backtest

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to merge two dataframes that that contain time series for individual stocks, so each column represents information on a stock. So Dataframe 1 has the stock prices and Dataframe 2 has P/E Ratios. My goal is to prepare a dataframe which I can use with the package backtest which requires a dataframe of this format:

```
library('backtest')
data(starmine)
```

Which has a structure like this:

```
date PRICE  symbol
date1 4.2    AAPL
date1 6.3    MSFT
date1 2.2    GE
date2 4.1    AAPL
date2 6.3    MSFT
date2 2.5    GE
```

So the dataset is grouped by months. My data comes in multiple dataframes which each contain the variable of interest (e.g. price, PE Ratio etc) for all stocks and all dates. An example:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1995/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 10)

a = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE) 
b = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
c = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
prices = data.frame(dates,a,b,c)       

a = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE) 
b = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
c = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
pe = data.frame(dates,a,b,c)
```

Can anyone how I can merge df1 and df2 in a way to obtain the same structure as in starmine? I thought of something like this:

```
> total <- merge(df1,df2,by=colnames)
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

This is the structure I would like to obtain:

```
date     price  pe  symbol  
1995/1/1 4.2    0.5     a
1995/1/1 6.3    0.4     b
1995/1/1 2.2    0.3     c
1995/2/1 4.1    0.4     a
1995/2/1 6.3    0.2     b
1995/2/1 2.5    0.1     c
1995/3/1 4.2    0.5     a
1995/3/1 6.3    0.4     b
1995/3/1 2.2    0.3     c
1995/4/1 4.1    0.4     a
1995/4/1 6.3    0.2     b
1995/4/1 2.5    0.1     c
```

Comment: What is `id` in `df2`?

Comment: Sorry, that should not be there, typo from a previous attempt. Thanks for pointing it out. I am going to fix it.

Comment: Looks like your question is about reshaping and not merging. Maybe I'm missing something. However, you can reshape each one of `df1` and `df2` to have a format like `starmine`, where the colum `symbol` will have values like `a`, `b`, or `c`. Is that what you want? If not, can you post how you expect your ideal output to be?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);
library(tidyr);
df1 %>% gather(symbol, price, -dates)` and see if this the format you're looking for.

Comment: That sounds like it could work but it groups by stock. So it stacks all the stocks at a time. But I want to group by date instead. I posted the structure I have in mind above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# example data
dates <- seq(as.Date("1995/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 10)

a = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE) 
b = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
c = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
prices = data.frame(dates,a,b,c)       

a = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE) 
b = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
c = sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)
pe = data.frame(dates,a,b,c)     

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# add dataset name as a column
prices$name = "price"
pe$name = "pe"

tbl_df(rbind(prices, pe)) %>%
  gather(symbol, value, -dates, -name) %>%   
  spread(name, value)

# # A tibble: 30 x 4
#        dates symbol    pe price
# *     <date>  <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 1995-01-01      a     1     0
# 2 1995-01-01      b     0     1
# 3 1995-01-01      c     0     0
# 4 1995-02-01      a     0     0
# 5 1995-02-01      b     0     1
# 6 1995-02-01      c     0     1
# 7 1995-03-01      a     0     0
# 8 1995-03-01      b     1     0
# 9 1995-03-01      c     0     0
# 10 1995-04-01     a     0     1
# # ... with 20 more rows
```

I'm using `tbl_df(rbind(prices, pe))` only for visualisation purposes. You don't really need `tbl_df()`, so you can use `rbind(prices, pe)` instead.

Comment: YES!!! That is perfect, thank you so much!!! I appreciate the quick help!!